# Only one application can output audio to bluetooth speaker at a time

Tags: pi-3b+, raspbian-stretch, bluetooth

I have a rpi 3b+ running on the latest Raspbian Stretch with desktop (2019 April 09), I updated/upgraded all packages to newest version, everything related to bluetooth & audio is kept default. I can connect rpi to my bluetooth speaker easily (on GUI - pixel desktop), select it as output audio, play music by VLC/open youtube in the browser and hear sound from it but as I mentioned on the title, only 1 application can output audio to bluetooth speaker at a time. To listen to music from VLC, I have to close browser and vice versa.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Is this a limitation of rpi/raspbian?

Thank you very much for your time and support!

Comment: The latest Raspbian version is Buster. Try it with Buster.

Comment: I have just tried with buster and nothing changes :(